# Query for multible properties?

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

```
{{#ask:
 [[Category:City]]
 [[Germany::]] 
|format=list
}}
```

Puts out: Berlin

How can I get the following to work so it outputs: Berlin, London?

```
{{#ask:
 [[Category:City]]
 [[Germany::]] 
 [[England::]]
|format=list
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{#ask:
 [[Category:City]]
 [[Germany::]] OR
 [[Category:City]]
 [[England::]]
|format=list
}}
```

Comment: Hmm, that did not work for me

Comment: try this :{{#ask:
 [[Category:City]]
 [[Germany::+]] OR [[England::+]]
|format=list
}}